# Determining name of the variable passed to function

Tags: bash, arguments

If I pass variable as a positional argument to a function, is it possible to determine the name of the variable used from inside the function, or I can only access its value?

I have a function `envir-export` that I can use to define an environment variable and store it in a special environment file that would then get sourced.

```
envir-export ()
 {
  nm="$1"
  vl="$2"
     
  envirs_trkrc="${HOME}/Opstk/envirs"
  echo "export ${nm}=${vl}" >> ${envirs_trkrc}/envirs.rc

  source ${envirs_trkrc}/envirs.rc
  echo "$nm exported with value $vl"
 }
```

Currently I am using by the following call

```
envir-export VERBOS 8
```

Using the name `VERBOS` with value `8`.

I would like to improve on this function, both in convenience, and also functionally.

For instance, if no value is supplied then I only export the name with a value being assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Common practice for achieving this is do something like

```
function envir-export () {
  name="${1%%=*}"
  value="${1##*=}"
  echo 'the name is '"$name"
  echo 'the value is '"$value"
}

envir-export VERBOS=8



$ function f () { name="${1%%=*}" ; value="${1##*=}" ; echo name "$name" ; echo value "$value" ; } ; f VERBOS=8
name VERBOS
value 8
$
```

Check the bash manpage and search for 'Parameter Expansion' for a howto on splitting the input into name and value.